# AdminListGroupsForUser returns user does not exist

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

My application is a process of authenticating with 2 services, one of which is AWS Cognito. When a user is authenticated *(so has the JWT Tokens that Cognito provides)*, I attempt to list the groups for that user via the `AdminListGroupsForUser` API call. I was getting the *UserNotFoundException* which was odd as the previous call had just authenticated that user with the same credentials?

I experimented with the following:

```
router.post("/groups/list", (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, limit, nextToken } = req.body;
    const listGroupsForUserParams = getAdminListGroupsForUserParams({
        email,
        limit,
        nextToken
    });
    const getUserParams = getAdminGetUserParams(email);

    cognitoClient.adminListGroupsForUser(listGroupsForUserParams, (listErr, listData) => {
        cognitoClient.adminGetUser(getUserParams, (getErr, getData) => {
            console.log(listErr);          // "UserNotFoundException"
            console.log(listData);         // null
            console.log(getErr);           // null
            console.log(getData);          // User
        });
    });
});
```

`listGroupsForUserParams` and `getUserParams` contain the same information which is:

```
{
    UserPoolId: "...",
    Username: "test@example.com"     // I use email as Username
}
```

I don't get how this makes sense that the former call cannot find the user in the pool but the latter can?

See *(for references)*:

- [AdminListGroupsForUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminListGroupsForUser-property)
- [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property)

Comment: Does your cognitoClient have region set correctly ?

Comment: @Deepthi yes, the region is correct. I imagine that if it wasn't, even the 2nd call to `adminGetUser` would fail

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and for some reason the `adminListGroupsForUser` function does not accept the email as username, whereas `adminGetUser` does.
I worked around that by retrieving the user data with `adminGetUser`. It returns the user and all its attributes. Retrieve the attribute value with name `sub` and use it as username for the `adminListGroupsForUser` call.

Something like this :

```
const getParams = {
    UserPoolId: "" /*put your user pool Id here*/,
    Username: "" /* email */
};

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminGetUser(getParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      return;
    }

    var sub;
    if (data.UserAttributes && data.UserAttributes.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.UserAttributes.length; ++i) {
        const attr = data.UserAttributes[i];
        if (attr.Name === 'sub') {
          console.log(attr);
          sub = attr.Value
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (!sub)
        return;

    const groupsParams = {
      UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
      Username: sub
    };  
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminListGroupsForUser(groupsParams, function(err, data) {
        /* Your code using groups here */
    });
});
```